# Extjs 4 Which syntax for component creation is better in terms of performance

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying to create a viewport and adding a panel to it. Which syntax do you think is better and why.

Traditional syntax.

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    Layout: 'fit',
    renderTo: 'main',
    items: [{
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel'))
    }]
});
```

new syntax.

```
var viewPort = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport');
viewPort.Layout = 'fit';
viewPort.renderTo = 'main';

var myPanel= Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel');

//Add myPanelto the viewport
viewPort.add(myPanel);
```

I prefer the latter syntax just because it is easier to read. Is there any performance loss by using this syntax.

Thanks in advance.
Vikas

Comment: I would be quite surprised if using one over the other leads to bottlenecks. Just use the approach that you and your team prefers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big difference is, that the *config way* is lazy. Lazy means, that until you *use* the component the code won't be executed, analyzed or even rendered.

The best way is (imho)

```
// hack example
Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
  layout: 'fit',
  items: [ {
    xtype : 'panel',
    ...
  } ],
  ...
});

// real world example
Ext.define('MyViewport', {
  extend : 'Ext.Viewport',
  layout: 'fit',
  items: [ {
    xtype : 'panel',
    ...
  } ],
  ...
});
myviewport = Ext.create('MyViewport');
```

However, it is more comfortable to use something likes this to archive more flexibility and reusability.

```
Ext.define('MyViewport', {
  extend : 'Ext.Viewport',
  layout: 'fit',
  initComponent : function(){
    this.items = this.buildItems();
    this.callParent();
  },
  buildItems: function() {
    return [ {
      xtype : 'panel',
      ...
    } ];
  },
  ...
});
myviewport = Ext.create('MyViewport');
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by the new syntax, if your loading object dynamically the .add() property is the way to go (portlets, loading items:[] from json from state such as persistent tabs, outlook like custom toolbar items). But for hacking something reasonable out I do this ...

```
var myPanel = new Ext.create('Ext.Panel', { .. });

Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [ myPanel ],
    ...
});
```

Comment: I want to load objects dynamically only because I prefer the way I have written my code, just to make the code more readable. So do you know if there is any performance loss when adding object dynamically versus using the configs?